# bootstrap nav-pills doesn't work without javascript

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap documentation they say You can activate a tab or pill navigation without writing any JavaScript. I try it like they said by simply specifying `data-toggle="tab"` on an element and by the `href` and the `ID`. But it doesn't work.
Do i have to add something else ?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked  col-xs-3">
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="one">one</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="two">two</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="three">three</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="four">four</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content col-xs-9">
  <div id="one" class="tab-pane active">
    Germany
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="tab-pane">
    France
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="tab-pane">
    Italy
  </div>
  <div id="four" class="tab-pane">
    Spain
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `#` in `href` where you call ID for example `href="#one"`

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked  col-xs-3">
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#one">one</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#two">two</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#three">three</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#four">four</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content col-xs-9">
  <div id="one" class="tab-pane active">
    Germany
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="tab-pane">
    France
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="tab-pane">
    Italy
  </div>
  <div id="four" class="tab-pane">
    Spain
  </div>
</div>
```

live [example](http://www.bootply.com/J4Lc5fq0qP)

Answer (score 0):

Check Ismail Farooq answer first, if still not work then you need to check did you add both jQuery library and bootstrap.js yet. Add those two two your page, jQuery first then bootstrap one and you will be fine.